# Smooth Scroll Jquery offset ignore on initial link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with a JQuery Smooth Scroll script. IT all works fine except for the initial press of any link to an anchor. On the first press after a page load, it ignores the offset. However if I then click on another link, the offset is recognised. This works with any anchor link on the navbar. And if I return to the one I pressed first, the offset is then correctly applied. It's just the initial press.

I'm using Bootstrap affix for the navbar that the anchors links are in (and it's the height of this navbar I'm trying to offset).

Here's the Smooth Scroll script:

```
(function ($) {

  var $navDepth;
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {
    $navDepth = 0;
  } else {
    $navDepth = 57;
  }

  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".scroll").click(function (event) { // When a link with the .scroll class is clicked
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action from occurring
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - $navDepth
      }, 500); // Animate the scroll to this link's href value
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="main" class="clearfix affix-top">
<div class="inner clearfix">
    <div class="menu-home-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-home-menu" class="menu l_tinynav1">
            <li id="menu-item-1944" class="scroll menu-item"><a class="scroll" href="#about-intro">About</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1945" class="scroll menu-item"><a class="scroll" href="#products-intro">Products</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1947" class="scroll menu-item"><a class="scroll" href="#projects-intro">Our Work</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1946" class="scroll menu-item"><a class="scroll" href="#news-intro">News</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-58" class="scroll menu-item"><a class="scroll" href="#contact-intro">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I'm not sure if it's a JQuery limitation, a bug with the script or something I'm missing.

Comment: Can you include the html as well?

Comment: Sorry, have added. It's a Wordpress generated menu but this is the output.

Comment: What is `this.hash` in the code?

Comment: I didn't write the script but I thought it was the # for the page anchors?